# Angular navigate to the same component more then one time

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-resolver

I am trying to navigate to the same route by using [routerlink] at the nav bar.
since in angular, redirect in to the same component to invoke ngOnint is not possible i faced this problem.

navigation at the nav bar

```
[routerLink]="['/customer/events']"
```

code in the constructor

```
  constructor(
     private navbarService: ServicesInterCustomerNavbarService,
     private router: Router,
     private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
     this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.selectedEventId = params["id"];
       this.getfunction();
    });
 }
```

my ngOnInit is like below

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.ongoing = [];
    this.navbarService.sendCurrentRoute("home");
    this.route.firstChild && this.route.firstChild.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.selectedEventId = params["id"];
      this.getfunction();
    });
}
getfunction() {
    this.ongoing = [];
    this.eventService.getOnging().subscribe(data => {
      this.ongoingEvents = data["data"].map(event => new CustomerEvent(event));
      if (!this.selectedEventId && this.selectedEventId != 'completed' && this.ongoingEvents.length >0) {
        this.redirectToEvent(this.ongoingEvents[0]._id);
      }
      if(this.ongoingEvents.length <1){
        this.redirectToEvent('-1');
      }
      this.dataLoaded = true;
    });
  }

  eventCreated(event_id: string) {
    this.router.navigate(["/customer/events/ongoing", event_id]);
    this.newEventWindow = false;

  }

  redirectToEvent(event_id: string) {
    this.router.navigate(["/customer/events/ongoing", event_id]);
  }
```

the router link after the click the router navigation for the first time is something like

> /customer/events/ongoing/sda3i4un34j3b42

but when i try to click the same navigation button, the router link is like below

> /customer/events/

the problem here is not calling the getfunction() and the OnInit
Can anyone figure this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you should just make a function redirect  which enable shouldreusestartergy

```
reInitComponent(){
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;

this.router.navigate(["/customer/events/ongoing", event_id]);

}
```

call this reInitComponent() whenever you want to reload and call all angular lifecycle hooks

Comment: thank you! But i used this approach. But what happens when the event id = -1, the component will re initiate in a never ending loop. any idea?

Comment: just check on ngOnInit method the parameter id if its -1 then dont call the the reload function else call the reload function

Comment: yes true, but according to my code, i do not pass any parameter through [routerlink], so there won't be any parameters. there for i used reuse strategy within the constructor.

Comment: just pass an optional or required parameter in routerLink code as :/id

Comment: Thanks! I fixed with this by using the below approach.

Answer (score 0):

We can add a query param which is dynamically change.

```
this.router.navigate(['/routedComponent'], {
   queryParams: {refresh: new Date().getTime()}
});
```

So we can check whether the query param is changed within the constructor and pass the function which we need to execute.

With this approach issue in routing to the same component with different params can be fixed